# $f$ is convex in $X$ open interval iff for every $(x_0,f(x_0))$ point on its graph there will be a line passing through that point

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, convex-analysis

$f$ is convex in   $X$ open interval iff for every $(x_0,(f(x_0)))$ point on its graph there will be a line passing through that point which will be under the graph of $f(x))$.

Proof.

I am reading proof and for $\to$. If $x_1,x_0 \in X$ and $x<x_0<x_1$ then

$\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$ and $\frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}$ are monotone increasing.

This part I can't understand why they are monotone increasing?

I know that if $f$ is convex in interval $X$ iff $x<z <y,\enspace x,y,z∈X$

$$\frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}\leq \frac{f(y)-f(z)}{y-z}$$

Comment: See $R$ in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Functions_of_one_variable.

Comment: Sorry for silly question but I don't understand why $R(x_1,x_2)$ is symmetric .

Comment: Multiply above and below by $-1$!

Comment: And how we can conclude from that,that it is monotone increasing?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the link you are missing is the following: For $x_0< x_1<x_2$
the inequality
$$ \frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0} \leq 
 \frac{f(x_2)-f(x_0)}{x_2-x_0} \leq
 \frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1} 
$$
looks like 3 inequalities but anyone of them boils down to (just multiply and reduce) the very same:
$$ f(x_2)(x_1-x_0) + f(x_1)(x_0-x_2)+f(x_0)(x_2-x_1) \geq 0$$
The outermost is the one you cite as definition of convexity, while the two middle ones state the monotonicity you are asking for. All are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The line of slope $m$ trough the point $(x_0, f(x_0))$ is below the graph of $f$ if and only if for every $x_1 < x_0 < x_2$ in the domain of $f$ we have
$$\frac{f(x_0) - f(x_1)}{x_0 - x_1} \le m \le \frac{f(x_2)-f(x_0)}{x_2 - x_0}$$

That would show that for any $x_1 < x_0 < x_2$  in the domain of $f$ we have
$$\frac{f(x_0) - f(x_1)}{x_0 - x_1} \le \frac{f(x_2)-f(x_0)}{x_2 - x_0}$$

This is equivalent to "$f$ is convex".